# Grails Form Select Options

Tags: forms, grails, select

The "select" form component in grails can have the form:

`<g:select name="user.age" from="${0..59}" value="${age}" noSelection="['':'-All-']"/>`

But if I need to add other options aside from the numbers, how would I do that (example options are: 0..59, All, "*/5", "*/10", etc,...)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<g:select from="${(0..59) + [ "All", "/5", "/10"]}" ... />
```

how about this?

Comment: Worked just fine once I replace the double quotes with single quotes around the "All", etc,...  Thanks!